# Subfield in Matlab table

Tags: matlab

Is it possible in matlab to created nested tables as below?
How can I access to the cells? For example I want to insert a value in Gender - Male... Can I do something like `Gender.Male.(1) = 54`?

```
         Gender
   __________________

    Male      Female
   _______   ________
     54          56
     55          57
     52          50
```

Comment: You can store more than one number in a column `Gender`, like `[54 56]`, but without the headers

Comment: I know :) it was just an example... I would like to learn how to do this in order to store multiple values for male and female. I edited the example

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html#btw1wrc-3) on the column `BloodPressure`

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to give subnames?

Answer (score 1):

If you want full flexibility (of course at cost of performance depending on how you use it) you are perhaps interested in a struct.

Example:

```
gender = struct();
gender.male = [54 55];
gender.female = [56 57 58];
```

You could now access the first male like so:

```
gender.male(1)
```

Note that you could do things like this as well:

```
gender = struct();
gender(1).person(1).age=55;
```

Comment: my purpose is quick data visualization. I would be glad to put the names in the table

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, just use a 2 column vector as an input:

```
data = table([54 56; 55 57; 52 50],'VariableNames',{'Gender'});
```

However, there is no way to give them sub-headers (`Male` and `Female`).

Using `structs` as in @Dennis answer is one way around this, but Tables are much more convenient (and fast) for storing and analyzing data.